# How to Synchronise playing videos in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5-8 videos, max 1-2 minutes each.

All the videos will be the same, with same duration. The only difference will be different filters applied to each one of them.

How do I make sure that all the videos run at the same time, such that user should not be able to see the difference?

Should let all the videos be buffered before I show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how accurate it has to be and what the user should be able to do I think it is either simple or very hard :) [Html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) has some nice material on the video tag. The code snippet below uses the same source video in two different video tags and plays them once they are both ready to be played:

```
<html>
<body>
<video controls id="vid1" preload="metadata"> <!-- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676422 -->
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
<video controls id="vid2"  preload="metadata"> <!-- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676422 -->
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
  </video>

<script>

var vid1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
var vid2 = document.getElementById("vid2");
var count = 0;
var playthem = function(e) {
    count++;
    if(count > 1) {
    alert('playing');
        vid1.play();
        vid2.play();        
    }
}

vid1.addEventListener('canplay', playthem, false);
vid2.addEventListener('canplay', playthem, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This plays well on my machine, but I'm not sure how it would be ok on older hardware. Another way if you need the videos to be perfectly synchronized be to use video+svg. The code below uses a single video tag and svg filters to "make copies" of that video tag. The benefit of this approach is that you ensure that you are only loading a single video and the controlling it through javascript will be simpler (since there is only one video source).

```
<div style="filter:url(#f2)">
<video style="filter:url(#f1)" controls id="vid1" preload="metadata"> <!-- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676422 -->
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
</div>
<svg id='image' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" height="200%" width="140%" transform="translate(90,0)">
    <feOffset dx="0" dy="360" result="B"/>
    <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="B"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="f2">
    <feOffset dx="480" dy="0" result="B"/>
    <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="B"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

</svg>
```